# Finding dlls to access sql server 2008R2 from a winform app

Tags: sql-server, winforms, dll

We have a Winforms app that speaks to SQL Server 2005 through six dlls that we keep in a folder of the Winforms apps solution. The SQL Server 2005 files we currently use are:

- BatchParser
- ConnectionInfo
- Replication
- SMOEnum
- SQLEnum
- WMIEnum
- SMO

We are moving to 2008 R2 and I've been trying to find out the exact list of dlls we need. I downloaded and run Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects  (32 bit) tried to find the individual files. I looked in the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies` directory as one post instructed me to do. I don't see a one to one correspondence to the names above (e.g. it looks like the SMO dll may now be called Configuration.Smo).

My problem is that I obviously need to know exactly which files I need to replace the 2005 versions. I also found out that since I'm running on a 64 bit system I will need the (x86) versions of these files. My questions are:

- What msi files will I need to download to get the 2008 R2 versions of these dlls?
- Where will the dlls be placed on my system once the msi is run so I can move them into my solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Fig001

Answer (score 0):

I believe that directory of yours is absolutely correct - that's what I'm seeing on my machine which has SQL Server 2008 R2 including the SMO components installed:

[image]

If you need the 32-bit versions, there's a "mirror" folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies
```

that contains the same files (and a few more) for you to use.

I do not know whether it's sufficient to just copy those DLL's to a folder and be done with it - if that doesn't work, you'll probably just have to require SMO as a pre-requisite for your application, or redistribute that suitable MSI yourself with your app installer.